# Getting value of one column ( price ) for max of another column (date) for a set of columns (make.model)

Tags: sql-server, join, max, row-number

I have a database table in MS SQL

```
Date      Make    Model    Price
4-Apr-17  Toyota  Avalon   34000
5-Apr-17  Merc    ML350    45000
6-Apr-17  BMW     5X       55000
7-Apr-17  Totoya  Camry    28000
8-Apr-17  Merc    ML350    46000
9-Apr-17  BMW     5X       54000
10-Apr-17 Totoya  Camry    25000
11-Apr-17 Merc    ML350    47000
12-Apr-17 Toyota  Avalon   36000
13-Apr-17 BMW     5X       53000
14-Apr-17 Toyota  Avalon   35500
15-Apr-17 BMW     5X       53500
16-Apr-17 Toyota  Avalon   35500
17-Apr-17 Merc    ML350    46500
```

I want to get the latest price of each model. My output should therefore be

```
Date      Make    Model    Price
10-Apr-17 Totoya  Camry    25000
15-Apr-17 BMW     5X       53500
16-Apr-17 Toyota  Avalon   35500
17-Apr-17 Merc    ML350    46500
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should use `ROW_NUMBER`:

```
WITH CTE AS
(
    SELECT *,
           RN = ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY Make, Model
                                  ORDER BY [Date] DESC)
    FROM dbo.YourTable
)
SELECT *
FROM CTE
WHERE RN = 1;
```

Answer (score 1):

One method is to use window function `row_number` with `top 1 with ties`:

```
select top 1 with ties *
from your_table
order by row_number() over (
        partition by make, model 
        order by [date] desc
        );
```

This way you can avoid subqueries/CTEs.